# How do I use credentials in Jenkins without pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I checked various wikis & forums, but everywhere pipeline has been used to access the credentials. Is it possible to access the credentials without a pipeline ?

Comment: What do you mean jenkins script? Sure also possible. You can find the information in the doku of the plugin.

Comment: I used Credentials & Credentials Binding plugin. They have mentioned code related to Pipeline. But I dont want to use pipeline, its a simple project to accept the credentials, do some activity and present the output